# rsync on macOS Catalina : filename overflows max-path len by 2

Tags: macos, catalina, path, rsync

I am trying to use `rsync` to transfer files to a Macbook Pro, like this :

```
rsync -avn --delete /Users/name/ fab@remote.local:/Users/home_name_from_old/
```

Unfortunately, I get the following errors on some files/directories :

```
filename overflows max-path len by 2
```

Here an example of what I get when I perform this operation of `rsync` above :

```
filename overflows max-path len by 2: Phd_2019_2020/Travail_2_Etude_de_la_stabilite_des_C_l_Probleme_avec_TAKAHASHI_ie_2_plateaux_dans_la_derivee_des_Cl_et_aussi_faire_varier_Omega_DE_sur_CAMB_et_regarder_si_les_P_k_changent_21_OCTOBRE_2019/Main_Directory_Work/TSAF_Main_Directory_STARTED_from_13_NOVEMBRE_2019/Test_Comparaison_SUITE_TAKAHASHI_STARTING_BY_USING_CAMB_PYTHON_CAR_PROBLEME_CUTOFF_SITUE_SOIT_A_2e-5_ET_LAUTRE_A_2e-4_ESSAYER_LA_METHODE_DINTERPOLATION_IMPLEMENTE_DANS_CAMB_avec_boost_accuracy_2_ET_k_per_login_75_29_DECEMBRE_2019/STUDY_of_PIC_SUITE_JE_PLOT_2_Pk_FOR_2_VALUES_DE_Omega_m_DIFF_IE_2_STEPS_DIFF_DONC_2_MEME_Z_FAUT_ETRE_DANS_ZONE_PATHO_cad_2e-4_CAD_LA_1st_MISE_EN_EVIDENCE_DU_PIC_AVEC_600_photoZ_ET_600_Pk_FILES_ET_JE_PLOT_AVANT_ET_APRES_CA_SUGGESTION_DE_LEWIS_05_01_2020/CAMB-1.0.12/fortran_original/SAVE_IMPORTANT_SCRIPTS_ET_Archive_current_Cl_MISE_EN_EVIDENCE_DES_2_PLATEAUX_DE_TAKAHASHI_AVEC_DER_15_PTS/Analysis_Pk_vs_Step_der_15_pts/Archive_WP_Pk_der_15_pts_step_8.283979084506619e-06/wm_dw2/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_316.dat
```

Or yet, now with `filename overflows max-path len by 1:` error :

```
filename overflows max-path len by 1: Phd_2019_2020/Travail_2_Etude_de_la_stabilite_des_C_l_Probleme_avec_TAKAHASHI_ie_2_plateaux_dans_la_derivee_des_Cl_et_aussi_faire_varier_Omega_DE_sur_CAMB_et_regarder_si_les_P_k_changent_21_OCTOBRE_2019/Main_Directory_Work/TSAF_Main_Directory_STARTED_from_13_NOVEMBRE_2019/Test_Comparaison_SUITE_TAKAHASHI_STARTING_BY_USING_CAMB_PYTHON_CAR_PROBLEME_CUTOFF_SITUE_SOIT_A_2e-5_ET_LAUTRE_A_2e-4_ESSAYER_LA_METHODE_DINTERPOLATION_IMPLEMENTE_DANS_CAMB_avec_boost_accuracy_2_ET_k_per_login_75_29_DECEMBRE_2019/STUDY_of_PIC_SUITE_JE_PLOT_2_Pk_FOR_2_VALUES_DE_Omega_m_DIFF_IE_2_STEPS_DIFF_DONC_2_MEME_Z_FAUT_ETRE_DANS_ZONE_PATHO_cad_2e-4_CAD_LA_1st_MISE_EN_EVIDENCE_DU_PIC_AVEC_600_photoZ_ET_600_Pk_FILES_ET_JE_PLOT_AVANT_ET_APRES_CA_SUGGESTION_DE_LEWIS_05_01_2020/CAMB-1.0.12/fortran_original/SAVE_IMPORTANT_SCRIPTS_ET_Archive_current_Cl_MISE_EN_EVIDENCE_DES_2_PLATEAUX_DE_TAKAHASHI_AVEC_DER_15_PTS/Analysis_Pk_vs_Step_der_15_pts/Archive_WP_Pk_der_15_pts_step_8.283979084506619e-06/wm_dw2/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_67.dat
```

and the output of `rsync --version` :

```
$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2018 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, no prealloc, file-flags

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

I guess the path is too long. How do I circumvent this problem?

Comment: Also: what is the output of `type rsync; rsync -V`?

Comment: This doesn't look like the Catalina version, did you install it via Homebrew or similar? Don't think the Catalina version behaves differently though, your paths are just too long. If this is a one-off transfer, you can try `scp -r` or a `tar` pipe via `ssh`.

Comment: @nohillside If I buy an external drive of 2TB and create a `Time Machine` image, could I transfer this image (or import it) inside the new MacBook Pro ?

Comment: Probably. You could probably also use migration assistant, use a more elaborate shell script to transfer sub-trees, shorten some top-level directory names (you can rename them on the target machine afterwards), or try to use `scp` instead of `rsync`

Comment: Also, the question shows that rsync doesn‘t support paths that long, the bounty message talks about scp instead. Which one has issues?

Comment: @noohillside both scp and rsync produce the same error : "`filename too long`".

Comment: Honestly, why don‘t you just shorten some directory names for the transfer and rename afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync has internal buffers to hold the names of files. These are hardcoded to have a value MAXPATHLEN which is defined to be an OS dependant value or  1024 in the code from https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/blob/d2a97a7ab492e0d0548708251309e077e6aa8c8b/rsync.h

So you path names are too long for either macos or rsync

Comment: Which command could allow me to copy all the files with a path over 1024 ? If I pass by a combination `rsync/ssh`, I guess the issue will remain. Maybe by copying on a harddrive, the command `cp` will circumvent this problem, won't it ?

Comment: If this is a OS limitation you can't do it in anyway

Comment: And sys/syslimits has PATH_MAX defined as 1024 so I think no C code can read paths of more that 1023 characters. Althogh I think HFS+ does allow more

Comment: Is HFS+ already present on my MacBook pro Catalina ? Maybe the solution is to use `Time Machine` utility to create a copy of my entire `/Users/user` directory with a `Airport Time capsule` ? but I don't know how to create a distant drive between the 2 MacBook pro, any help is welcome

Comment: If I buy an external drive of 2TB and create a `Time Machine` image, could I transfer this image (or import it) inside the new MacBook Pro ?